# Insufficient Privileges on Profile records

Tags: profile, insufficient-privileges

Currently using an Enterprise Edition org, but somehow my system admin user  lost the ability to modify profiles and cannot see the profile setup in the setup menu.

And whenever I'm trying to access a profile record detailed page, It's giving me the Insufficient Privileges error which is odd since I'm a system admin user.

NOTE:My user has the standard System Admin Profile.

[image]

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: Can you go to setup and my profile to check if you are really a 'System Administrator' may be someone accidentally changed your profile.

Comment: Yep, my user has the standard "System Administrator" assigned to it.

Comment: Some of our customers have the same problem, we have asked to support

Comment: Same thing we're also waiting for the response from support. Better log this as a known issue with sf.